# C++ bitset inheritance - How to fix type error with logical operators?

Tags: c++

I am inheriting class from STL bitset.

Reasons:

1. I need same size bitsets in multiple places, so I want to define a type for them.
2. I want to add some extra methods in future, so I need a class.

Here's a sample code.

```cpp
#include <bitset>

class MySet : public std::bitset<256> {

};

// This is not a real function, just PoC
MySet intersection(MySet &a, MySet &b) {
    return a & b;
}
```

But on & operator I get error:

```
error: could not convert 'std::operator&<256>((& a)->MySet::<anonymous>, (& b)->MySet::<anonymous>)' from 'std::bitset<256>' to 'MySet'
```

What should I add to be able to use all logical operators defined in bitset for my class?

Comment: `I am inheriting class from STL bitset.` - do yourself a favor and don't.

Comment: Yes, don't inherit. Otherwise implement your own operator overload that calls the bitset one.

Comment: FWIW, `using my_bitset = std::bitset<256>` lets you have your name but still use a `std::bitset`.

Comment: `std::bitset` already provides [`operator&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_logic2).

Comment: @NathanOliver but i will not be able to add my own methods.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin Depending on what you want to do you can make them free functions instead of member functions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, I know, but when I try to use it, I get type error.

Comment: @SergeyA but why?

Comment: @NathanOliver I prefer OOP approach. Operators can be inherited. I just don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: You need to tell the compile how to convert a `bitset` into a `MySet` (via a constructor).

Comment: @NathanOliver could you please provide an example how to do that?
I mean what exacly should I put into constructor if i just want to cast bitset to MySet?

Comment: You should just need `MySet(const std::bitset<256>& bs) : std::bitset<256>(bs) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `a & b` cannot be implicitely converted to `MySet`, since there is no suitable definition for such conversion. The workaround is to simply declare a constuctor. This:

```
public:
    MySet(const std::bitset<256>& b)
            : std::bitset<256>{b} { }
```

will be enough to make the code compile.

Comment: Thanks! It works now!
But I wonder, how much overhead it introduces.
Same function but with `using MySet = bitset<256>;` compiles into a bit shorter machine code.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin that depends on your exact code, your compilar and your compiler options. Did you compare the generated assembly with full optimisations enabled and on release mode?

Comment: Class version: https://godbolt.org/z/KJidtk
Alias version: https://godbolt.org/z/FGg_bx

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin on the other hand, if I remove your `#pragma`s like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bSRnVt) and [that](https://godbolt.org/z/okHAKa), the code becomes identical.